# Hibernate caching stale data: many to many unidirectional mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have a many-to-many relationship as below (in a library type application):

```
User:    
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_book",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "fk_book")}
)
private List<Book> books = null;

Book:
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, 
            mappedBy = "books", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> users;
```

Problem: When I edit the name of a book, the value gets updated in the table, however because of hibernate caching, the User objects still hold a reference to the old book entity. So while in back-end I have the correct Book value, on UI I still see stale values. I am using ehcache and also enabled second level caching.
Cache configuration:

```
<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false"
        />
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        />

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
        />
```

I am also using OEMIV filter.

Comment: What's your question exactly? How is the cache configured? Do you use session-per-transaction? session-per-conversation? session-per-request?

Comment: Question: How can I make hibernate not cache the old values after I have edited them ? I have OEMIV Filter enabled. Cache is configured as mentioned above (recent update)

Comment: You haven't made the association cachable, so it must not be in the second-level cache. We don't know how you configured the cache on the Book entity. And we don't know how you edit the name of the book: through Hibernate? Same JVM?

Comment: I edit the name of the Book through hibernate (from within same JVM). No caching is configured specific to Book entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to call the method

```
Flush()
```

This is because any changes you make to the first or second level cache will be stored into the cache, however it is not until you flush the cache, that the data is actually stored into the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My cache is getting flushed for sure, as I can see the data being stored in the database (mysql).